# Sending [NSDictionary]() to API as JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2, type-conversion, nsdictionary

I have a `[NSDictionary]()` created from a Realm Result.
My main goal is to parse this `[NSDictionary]()` to an JSON and then send it to the API via Alamofire, but with this data I have to send the users Password and details.

```
let orderRequestUserValues  = [  "ClientID": "TEST",
                                 "UserName": "sysadmin",
                                 "Password": "123456",
                                 "ModuleID": "StockProcessing",
                                 "FunctionID": "SetStockOrder",
                                 "TransmissionFlags": 32,
                                 "TransmissionMethod": 5,
                                 "RequestParameters":
                                 [
                                   "OrderType": 1,
                                   "Notes": "John Is Reordering",
                                   "ListofStockItemOrderData": //<--[NSDictionary]() data has to come here
                                 ]
                               ]
```

With this `orderRequestUserValues` I have to send the `[NSDictionary]()`
as "ListofStockItemOrderData" as can be seen by the comment.

I am Pretty new this so please do not ridicule me.
I want to know how do I convert this `orderRequestUserValues` and the `[NSDictionary]()` to a JSON that I can send via Alamofire.
The end product that the JSON receives must look like this:

[image]

**EXTRA INFO**
Here is how I converted my Realm stored data to NSDictionary

```
   extension Object {
   func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    let properties = self.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
    let dictionary = self.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(properties)
    let mutabledic = NSMutableDictionary()
    mutabledic.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)

    for prop in self.objectSchema.properties as [Property]! {
        // find lists
        if let nestedObject = self[prop.name] as? Object {
            mutabledic.setValue(nestedObject.toDictionary(), forKey: prop.name)
        } else if let nestedListObject = self[prop.name] as? ListBase {
            var objects = [AnyObject]()
            for index in 0..<nestedListObject._rlmArray.count  {
                let object = nestedListObject._rlmArray[index] as AnyObject
                objects.append(object.toDictionary())
            }
            mutabledic.setObject(objects, forKey: prop.name)
        }} 
         return mutabledic }}
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct 3 dictionaries to achieve what you want.

- 1st dictionary: orderRequestUserValues.
- 2nd dictionary: requestParameters.
- 3rd dictionary: listofStockItemOrderData.

Then you do this:

```
NSDictionary *listofStockItemOrderData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@3,@"StockItemUnique",
                                          @5,@"StockQty",
                                          @0,@"StockUnitCost",
                                          @1,@"OrderLocationUnique",nil];

NSDictionary *requestParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@1,@"OrderType",
                                   @"John Is Reordering",@"Notes",
                                   listofStockItemOrderData,@"ListofStockItemOrderData", nil];

NSDictionary *orderRequestUserValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST",@"ClientID",
                                        @"sysadmin",@"UserName",
                                        @"123456",@"Password",
                                        @"StockProcessing",@"ModuleID",
                                        @"SetStockOrder",@"ClientID",
                                        @32,@"TransmissionFlags",
                                        @5,@"TransmissionMethod",
                                        requestParameters,@"RequestParameters",nil];
```

Finally, you convert the dictionary to NSData json to post to your web service:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:orderRequestUserValues options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Comment: I already have an [NSDictionary]() for the "ListofStockItemOrderData" it is my realm data. How would I join the 3 dictionaries?

Comment: And this is Objective c?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. I don't have much experience with swift.

Comment: If you already have listofStockItemOrderData dictionary, then you can add it straight to requestParameters without initialising it like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is what I did to get the results I wanted:

```
var orderRequestUserValues : Dictionary  = [  "ClientID": "TEST",
                                                  "UserName": "sysadmin",
                                                  "Password": "123456",
                                                  "ModuleID": "StockProcessing",
                                                  "FunctionID": "SetStockOrder",
                                                  "TransmissionFlags": 32,
                                                  "TransmissionMethod": 5


    ]

    var requestParameters : Dictionary = [
                                           "OrderType": 1,
                                            "Notes": "John Is Reordering"

    ]



    requestParameters.updateValue(objectDictionaries, forKey: "ListofStockItemOrderData")

    orderRequestUserValues.updateValue(requestParameters, forKey: "RequestParameters")



   //print(orderRequestUserValues)


    do{

    let newDict = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(orderRequestUserValues, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

    let decoded = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(newDict, options: [])
        print(decoded)
```